# Relationships between two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one question, so there are two tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Account (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
    balance DOUBLE NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES User (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Operation (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    source_id INT NOT NULL,
    destination_id INT NULL,
    operation_type VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    date DATE NOT NULL,
    total DOUBLE NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (source_id) REFERENCES Account (id)
    -- Wrong!!!
    FOREIGN KEY (destination_id) REFERENCES Account (id)
);
```

Fields `source_id` and `destination_id` have to refer to Account table because each operation should have an account source and not required destination account.

If I have set up `source_id` as a foreign key in the Operation table that refers to the Account table. How can I make the correct relationship between `destination_id` and Account table?
I believe it should be in a third table, but I can't figure out how it could be organised in a proper way.

Comment: Why do you think the FK destination_ID  back to account.id is wrong?  Say I have a ship record with a origin state and delivery state both pointing back to a list of states in a table.  Would that be wrong? (no) So why would ensuring the destination_ID is a valid Account if provided be incorrect?  This just means when you need both accounts in a query from an operation, you have to join to account table TWICE once for source and once for destination.  Again, nothing wrong here.

Comment: Looks correct as xQbert said. The FK just validates that the destination_id you put in that table is a valid account_id, and that if you have a account_id as destination_id in that table, you can't delete the account row until you remove it from the operation. Looks good.

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys, I had doubts regarding second FK to the same table but it looks like a good solution.